# How to revert back to older version of Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, command-line-interface

I am new in Ionic 3 CLI, I found that 
`Ionic run android` no longer works,
It works as `Ionic cordova run android`,

Is there any way I can go back to IONIC older CLI?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can downgrade angular-cli installation to 1 by running commands in terminal:

> npm uninstall -g angular-cli
>
> npm cache clean
>
> npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0